# Read and Write fonts file in Android

Tags: android, svg, httprequest

I want to download different files like

> (.css .txt .js .ttf .eol .svg .png and etc...)

from server and place it into sdCard. So far i am pretty successful in downloading and saving files of (.txt .css .js .png etc..) but problem arises when i try to download my fonts folder which includes following files

> .svg .eot .ttf .woff  and .otff

Every files downloaded correctly but My fonts are not properly applied in my local html ... Here is my code

```
File localConfigfile = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/Avalon/www/" + path);
if (localConfigfile.exists()) {
                    localConfigfile.delete();
String responseString = RequestMgr
                                .GetWebSource(DomainName + "/" + Heirarchy
                                        + "/" + Serverpath);
out = new FileOutputStream(localConfigfile);
                        out.write(responseString.getBytes());
                        out.flush();
                    }
```

For Example My .svg have a size of 198k but in my local folder size changed into 94k. It means it is not downloaded correctly.

Comment: What problem exactly?

Comment: Like it is not same formatted in my local folder. For Example My .svg have a size of 198k but in my local folder size changed into 94k. It means it is not downloaded correctly.